# Invalid JSON text in argument 2 - json_contains in MySQL 5.7.8

Tags: mysql, json, mysql-5.7

I have a database with one column that is JSON of strings (ex. ["ART","LIT"], etc.).  I want to search it using `json_contains`.

However, when I try:

```
json_contains(\`column_name`,"ART")
```

It errors saying:

> Invalid JSON text in argument 2 to function json_contains: "Invalid value." at position 0 in 'ART'.

Note that `json_contains` doesn't error with numbers in the place of "ART", just with strings. Any idea what I can do to fix/get around this?

Answer (score 75, accepted):

Apparently, it treats integers differently from strings.  While `` json_contains(`column_name`,"1") `` is a valid call, to check if it contains "ART", you must use `` json_contains(`column_name`,'"ART"') `` (note the double quoting).

That resolved my issue!

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-search-functions.html

val is also a JSON object type ' "ART" '

Comment: do you know how to using this in spring jpa nativequery?

Comment: You can use [JSON_QUOTE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-creation-functions.html#function_json-quote) for quoting strings. Example: `json_contains(\`column_name\`, json_quote("ART"))`

Answer (score 11):

If the column name store tags only (one level array), like ["ART","LIT","SPORTS"]

```
JSON_CONTAINS(column_name, 'ART', '$')
```

If the column name store an key-value array like {"tag":"ART","other":"NONE"}

```
JSON_CONTAINS(column_name, 'ART', '$.tag')
```

Finally if tag value is inside a parent array, you need to use path like this:

```
JSON_CONTAINS(column_name, 'ART', '$.parent.tag')
```

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-search-functions.html#function_json-contains

Answer (score 4):

If your candidate type is string,
just add double quotes on your candidate then try again.

```
json_contains(\`column_name`,'"ART"')
```

[JSON_CONTAINS(target, candidate[, path])](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-search-functions.html#function_json-contains)