# JSON_CONTAINS string everywhere in the structure

Tags: php, mysql, json, laravel, eloquent

I have a JSON column in my MySQL database (5.7.25) that can contain any type of JSON structure (so I do not have any property that is common to all the rows)

How can I perform a query through laravel ELOQUENT in order to search rows that match a string in one of the property of the JSON column?

I tried with this:

```
JSON_CONTAINS(`payload`, "key")
```

But mySQL throws the following exception:

```
Invalid JSON text in argument 2 to function json_contains: "Invalid value." at position 0
```

For example if the structure is similar to this:

```
{first_name:"John", "last_name":"Smith", "company":"Demo Company"}
```

I would like to search for all the rows that contain the word "Demo" in any of the properties (Also if the string is a substring of the json property value).

The only working way I found was the following:

```
JSON_SEARCH(payload, 'one', '%Demo%') IS NOT NULL
```

But it seems to be a bit slow. So I am asking if there's a faster way

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33513625/invalid-json-text-in-argument-2-json-contains-in-mysql-5-7-8 help?

Answer (score 1):

The post title is different from the actual question, but for people who are wondering how to search inside anywhere in JSON, you could use simply a LIKE.

Given a json:

```
 {
    "rule": 4,
    "triggers": {
        "then": {
            "field": "Sessions_Remaining__c",
            ...
        },
        "when": ""
    }
}
```

You wont get any value by using:

```
SELECT * WHERE JSON_CONTAINS(json,'"Sessions_Remaining__c"')
```

So you can use instead:

```
SELECT * WHERE json LIKE '%"Sessions_Remaining__c"%';
```