# Is there a bug in mysql 5.7 while processing json data types?

Tags: mysql, json, laravel

I am working on laravel project using mysql. Recently I updated my ubuntu and after that I am getting error while fetching data from mysql db using `json_extract()` method in where clause.

Until today I was able to fetch data using below code in laravel model:

```
return self::where([
            'transaction_details->compensation_status' => Compensation::GIVEN,
            'transaction_type' => self::COMPENSATION,
            'transaction_details->compensation_type' => Compensation::MANUAL
        ])->orderBy('updated_at')->get();
```

Here `transaction_details` column holds the json data, while `transaction_type` is an integer column.

So above code when dumped, it gives me the SQL query:

```
select * from `transactions` where (json_unquote(json_extract(`transaction_details`, '$."compensation_status"')) = 1 and `transaction_type` = 7 and json_unquote(json_extract(`transaction_details`, '$."compensation_type"')) = 2) order by `updated_at` asc
```

And when I run this query I am getting some unexpected error:

**#3141 - Invalid JSON text in argument 1 to function json_extract: "Missing a comma or '}' after an object member." at position 196.**

I also tried make this query shorter, keeping only one condition so that I can get rid of any error at position 196.

```
select * from `transactions` where json_unquote(json_extract(`transaction_details`, '$."compensation_status"')) = 1 order by `updated_at` asc
```

Now this query do not have anything at position 196 but still the same error.

I guess this the bug in latest mysql.

Please do help me in this regards.

EDIT:
This is the json data the `transaction_details` holds

```
{"message":"fgdfgdfg","referral_compensation_date":"2019-11-30","compensation_status":1,"compensation_type":2,"allocated_count":"-NA-","daily_job_count":"-NA-","allocation_date":"2019-11-30"}
```

Comment: are you using mysql or mariaDB.?

Comment: @KamleshPaul I am using mysql.

Comment: have to checked this ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33513625/invalid-json-text-in-argument-2-json-contains-in-mysql-5-7-8

Comment: @KamleshPaul Thanks but this does not resolve my error.

Comment: Have you checked if the data itself isn't corrupted/malformed?

Comment: json_extract() need json object or array and your are giving `(transaction_details, '$."compensation_status"')` this that's why https://database.guide/json_extract-return-data-from-a-json-document-in-mysql/

Comment: I have updated my question, added the json data which is I am concerned

Comment: have you checked near `Missing a comma or '}' after an object member` .?

Comment: Yes I checked, even JSON_VALID() returns 1 when checking the data.

Comment: then restart you pc may be ^_^

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Invalid JSON text in argument 2 - json\_contains in MySQL 5.7.8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33513625/invalid-json-text-in-argument-2-json-contains-in-mysql-5-7-8)

Comment: I tested your SQL query with the JSON value you show, but I get no error. Tested on MySQL 5.7.27.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is fully correct and is executed without problems with shown sample data on MySQL 5.7.

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=cdc447827ad7f3ed77968bb50f559824)

The problem is NOT in a query. Check the data you're processing. Look for a comma in a value, non-printed char, special chars, errorneously truncated values, etc.

Try to find one problematic record (add a condition by ID range, process a half of records, a quarter, ... until one record caused error found). Copy this record to separate table, ensure it is still problematic, backup this table, and share backup script.

Comment: Thank you, it has brought some relief for me. I shall check it again in my system as per the steps you mentioned. I shall revert you back tomorrow morning.

Comment: This is completely strange phenomena. Yesterday that query was not at all running but today it is running as expected.May be my system was needed to be booted after ubuntu software updation. Thank you again for providing the dbfiddle.